# ArcGIS Server GP Service - RasterIO.dll crashing ArcSOC.exe

Tags: arcgis-server, arcpy

I've been having a [terrible time this week](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28775/esri-geoprocessing-script-runs-fine-in-desktop-crashes-as-geoprocessing-serv) turning some very simple geoprocessing scripts into gp services on ArcGIS Server 10 SP 4.  In the case of the linked post, I found that using certain raster formats seemed to be the trouble maker on ArcGIS Server.

Once again, I have a small, simple script that performs a viewshed analysis.  It runs perfectly from ArcGIS desktop.  As a gp service, all hell breaks loose...

Whats interesting about this case is that the analysis itself completes without error.  All of the processing is done within a gdb - and all output feature classes are being produced.  This eliminates the possibility of a permission related error.

The output of the gp service is a feature set - to be loaded from one specific feature class in my processing file gdb.  The feature class is always there, however the gp service crashes before the feature set is ever sent to client.  When I log into the ArcGIS Server, there will be windows message box open saying the ArcSOC.exe has stopped working.  Looking the Event Viewer; the faulting module is RasterIO.dll.

ArcGIS Server has no log entry for this crash.  All attempts to trap any errors in the python script itself dont yield anything either.

Has anyone experienced anything similar, or have any idea how I can get more useful information on the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that reverting back to arcgisscripting (instead of arcpy) - everything works as expected.